# Read contents of CSV file into list and print contents of list into web text field using pyautogui

Tags: for-loop, copy, pyautogui

When I create a list from values in a CSV file, I am able to print out the contents of the list using the built in print function, but when I try to enter the elements of the list into an input box using pyautogui,only the first element of the list is printed.

Here is the code which is not working with screenshot of error attached.

Idle Error Message

[image: 1]

```
import csv, pyautogui, time


file = open('serials.csv', 'r')

serial_list = list(csv.reader(file))
file.close


print(serial_list)

time.sleep(5)
i = 0
for serial in serial_list:
    pyautogui.typewrite(serial_list[i][i])
    i +=1
```

I was able to get the desired results using the Python code below which I generated using VBA, but would like to learn how to do this properly using Python.

```
import pyautogui, time

time.sleep(3)



pyautogui.write("2300-xxxx1")
pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.write("2300-xxxx2")
pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.write("2300-xxxx3")
pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.write("2300-xxxx4")
pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.write("2300-xxxx5")
```

Answer (score 0):

yo, I think issue is in this line of code:

```
pyautogui.typewrite(serial_list[i][i])
```

Here, you trying to access a specific element of the 2D list serial_list using serial_list[i][i] where i is the index variable. However, this will only give you the first element of the list.

You should use the variable serial that you defined in the for loop to access the current element of the list:

```
pyautogui.typewrite(serial)
```

Also, since the serial_list is a 2D list of strings, you want to convert the elements of list to strings before passing it to the pyautogui.typewrite() function like this:

```
for serial in serial_list:
    pyautogui.typewrite(str(serial))
```

Also, you should call the file.close method with paranthesis file.close() to close the file properly.

Also, you should use the pyautogui.press('tab') function after each pyautogui.typewrite() function call to move to the next input box.

So the final code will look like:

```
import csv, pyautogui, time

file = open('serials.csv', 'r')

serial_list = list(csv.reader(file))
file.close()

print(serial_list)

time.sleep(5)
for serial in serial_list:
    pyautogui.typewrite(str(serial))
    pyautogui.press('tab')
```

Now it will work.
why? cuz ️